# How can find a combobox from string?

Tags: c#, combobox, controls

as I know combobox isn't member of System.Windows.Forms.Control class

I used this code for find control

```
Control ctrFindControl = this.Controls.Find("FindSomething", false)[0];
```

but how can find a combobox from string?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= cmbAccount1.Items.Count; i++)
{
   string txtCategory = "cmbCategory" + i;

   Control cmbBoxCategory;
   cmbBoxCategory = this.Controls.Find(txtCategory , false)[0];

   cmbBoxAccount.Items.Add("a");
   cmbBoxAccount.Items.Add("b");
   cmbBoxAccount.Items.Add("c");
   cmbBoxAccount.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Just cast the control you found to a `ComboBox`:

```
ComboBox cmbBoxCategory = (ComboBox)this.Controls.Find(txtCategory, false)[0];

cmbBoxCategory.Items.Add("a");
cmbBoxCategory.Items.Add("b");
cmbBoxCategory.Items.Add("c");
cmbBoxCategory.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

The `ComboBox` isn't a member of the `Control` class, but it is derived from it, which is why your current code compiles. You have to cast it to the more derived type, in this case a `ComboBox`, before you can access those members and properties that belong to a `ComboBox`.

Comment: Thank you, It's true, but when for loop going to second loop it give an exception:  Index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: no I have 20 cmbCategory combobox in my form, cmbCategory1 to cmbCategory20

Comment: I tested first loop with messagebox it will find cmbCategory1 but it can't find cmbCategory2 in second loop

Comment: Oh Thanks, I didn't change second combobox name to cmbCategory2 , and now It doing work